# need to use hooks(useSelector) but want to return only the Value that i got from redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I want to use a normal function to connect with redux store and get the value which is a boolean i don't want to return any html elements what should i do?

```
export function someFunction(){
    let isAdminProfile = useSelector(state => selectorFunction.isAdmin(state));
    return isAdminProfile
}
let value = someFunction()
```

**I need something like this in react?**

Comment: Refer to docs "build your own custom hook" https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook

Comment: What's your end goal?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom hook to return the value. Here's how it would look like:

```js
function useIsAdminProfile() {
    return useSelector(state => selectorFunction.isAdmin(state));
}

export default function MyComponent() {
    const isAdminProfile = useIsAdminProfile();

    return (
        <div>Is Admin: {isAdminProfile}</div>
    );
}
```

Note that by convention the hooks should start with `use`. For instance, `useIsAdminProfile`. You could read more over [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html#extracting-a-custom-hook).

**However**, if your end goal is to return the value itself, I wouldn't recommend this approach as it has an additional overhead with no advantage. Instead, what you have in the mentioned snipped is completely alright. Additionally, it could be further shortened to the following:

```js
const isAdminProfile = useSelector(selectorFunction.isAdmin);
```